# How can a triangle have a sum exceeding 180 degrees in a curved space?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, mathematics, geometry, space

I was reading a book to understand the limits of the euclidean space I understand that lines that are parallel in 2d can meet in 3d space like on a sphere but it is hard to imagine or fathom why the deviation in the angle is happening
what I deduced is is that  the 2d space of the sphere is actually curved so what appears to be straight in 2d is not straight in 3d so the angles won't be the same as in 2d space they will be different relevant to our system?

Comment: thanks for all the wonderful answers if I could hardly pick one to accept since they all where very useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are three diagrams to illustrate that the angle sum of a triangle can differ from $180^\circ$.

[image]

The Wikipedia article [Spherical Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_geometry) might be of interest?
It has a nice illustration relating to measuring angles of a triangle on the Earth.
[image]

Comment: If I do draw a triangle on a flat paper and then start bending it in  half  to form something like an open space would I be able to notice the distortion in the sum of the angles or 1 since the triangle is too small I would not ,or would the fact paper not form an open space to begin with

Comment: The paper will need to stretch.

Answer (score 2):

The angles are the same in 2d and 3d! Your example of the sphere is perfect. If you take the North pole and two points on the equator then a triangle with 3 x 90 degrees is formed.

1. If, for this triangle on the sphere, you use the 2d space rules you will say the lines are straight and the angles are 90 degrees.
2. If you use the 3d space rules you will say the lines are not straight, but the angles are still 90 degrees.

So the difference is only in what you call a straight line, not in how you define an angle. (The metric of space does not affect the latter, only the former.)

Comment: in the book they gave an example of using the angles of a triangle to find if our space is flat or curved and when doing an experiment on very distant star from earth we got  the sum of the angles to be greater than 180 , they tried to do a demonstration to this on a sphere to understand the limitations

Comment: so they drew a line from a point A on the pole to  two points b and c on (b and c are different)  the equator so that angles down are 90 for ab and ac  and so that it does not really achieve phythagors theorem since the bc ^2+ca^2 does not equal ab^2  and so they said the angles can be larger

Comment: I think that maybe when we draw the lines that are straight in 2d since the sphere is not 2d they can only appear to be straight if we stretch the angle ?

Comment: The sphere *is* 2d (we call it a "ball" if we mean the volume enclosed by the sphere https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(mathematics) )

Comment: indeed for the second example I meant a ball do excuse me for the confusion

Comment: OK in that case a triangle with straight lines in 3d will have its sides run internally through the ball, not over the spherical surface like a triangle on the 2d sphere would have. So you then have two different triangles, with different anges and different sides, only the vertices are the same. (To be honest I don't see whether there is now any remaining problem...)

Comment: I think now it is clear  this was really helpful thanks for your answer really helped

Answer (score 1):

So in essence a straight line for us (in respect to a 3D space) is in fact a curved line on a 2D space, this essentially means that the lines are "stretched" over the curve of our spherical surface which means that the angle can be greater but if you were to put said line back into a 2D space the line would appear curved. In essence a straight line in a 3D sphere will be curved in 2D. So I believe that this should be concurrent with what you are saying?

Answer (score 1):

You can imagine putting mirrored square tiles on a disco ball. No matter how hard you try, you end up leaving awkward gaps between the tiles or having to cut parts off the tiles to completely cover the spherical surface. In 2D space we can completely cover the surface with perfect squares indefinitely, without any awkward gaps. This should illustrate that curved surfaces in 3D space are fundamentally different to flat 2D surfaces and angles do not add up in the same way.